# Connection String for Oracle in OraDb11g_home1 Driver

Tags: database, oracle, connection-string

I know that connection string questions are a dime-a-dozen, but I've got a new one.

I created a System DSN to talk to an Oracle database that I have locally on my machine. I put in all the info and hit the test button, and it says that it's successful. I'm using the OraDb11g_home1 driver.

When I try to put together a connection string for an application that uses ODBC, of course I can't get it to work.

One of the connection string attributes that they say that they require in their documentation is something called "Provider." What is this?

One of the most recent strings that I've used includes the following.

```
Driver={Oracle in OraDb11g_home1};Server=\\localhost:1521\local;Uid=mike;Pwd=password
```

Can anyone please offer any suggestions? Thanks,

mj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was trying to use an application that was using 32-bit ODBC and the DSNs that I created were 64-bit.